# Load data to recyclerview by chunks

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, retrofit

let's assume I have a list of 2000 items. it's clearly not right to load them all at once but split the list to 20 items each time with an infinite recyclerview.
now if my http request returns a file with JSON array of 2000 items. how can I cut it to 20 items on each request?
I'm using retrofit and OkHttp as my client.

Comment: The backend should support pagination

Comment: If loading the json file doesn't take too long, using the recyclerview with 2000 items won't be an issue, recyclerview reuses the cells

Comment: use pagination it will help